# How to improve the fragment display efficiency? How to track the place of bottleneck?

Tags: android

I design an app for the restaurant menu, running on Pad. The UI is 2 parts, the left one is a category panel. Clicking one category, the right area will display a fragment.

I feel the fragment switch is too slow. I had thought the reason is at FragmentManager's replace action, but after tracking here, the replace code is just cost around 3 milliseconds. So here is not the display bottleneck. The code is

```
FragmentManager fragMgr = MainActivity.getInstance().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction trans = fragMgr.beginTransaction();
trans.replace(R.id.dishdisplayarea_layout, frag);
trans.commit();
```

To improve fragment's display speed, I build the fragments' instance in the MainActivity's onCreate method and store them in a map. Every time while I need to display one, I just get it from the map, so I don't think the time is wasted on building fragment's view.

```
//get fragment object from map
DishDisplayFragment frag = MainActivity.getInstance().getMapDishDisplayFragments().get(category2Id);


//the fragment's onCreateView function, just return an exist view object
public class DishDisplayFragment extends Fragment {
    private View view;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return view;
    }
    ......
}
```

In every fragment, there is around 30 myself component which I named as DishComponent, and for one DishComponent, including 9 layouts, 6 ImageView, 2 TextView and one button. Since the DishComponent layout XML file is too more code, I just attach a snapshot of it here.
[DishComponent structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkG5E.png)
I don't know if there too many components in the fragment, then make the fragment replace action very slow. My device is Samsung Tab E with 1.5G memory and a 1.3GHz four-core CPU. I tracked the app's memory, it is less 30M, compared with the device 1.5G memory, the apps consume on memory is not big. So I doubt the bottleneck is CPU. Another evidence is that while I run this app in Android Virtual Device on the computer, the operation is very smooth, obviously, the computer's CPU is more powerful then pad's.

I tracked the CPU time too on Pad. I found most of the time is used for Handler and Choreographer and ViewRootImpl. Actually, I don't know about android's framework. I don't know whether this info is useful to improve my app. I attach it here wish it is useful.
[the CPU time for a replace operation of fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTbAL.png)
Then track the CPU graph, I found the CPU only use 30%. Does this mean only one core working for my app and other cores are idle? If so, how can design to make all cores work together?

I also think the point that my pad's hardware is too low level. I used Antutu, an app to measure the phone/pad's running speed. My pad just scores 18000, but the iPhone7 can get 150000 scores on Antutu. So is the hardware the main reason?

Now, I list my questions here

- how to locate the position where leads to fragment replace action slow?
- how could I use 2 cores when an app needs more calculation?
- how to design more optimized layout to make android run/display quickly?
- Are there other skills to make fragments replace quickly if the reason is from the hardware?

Comment: Does Hierarchy Viewer show any possible issues: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html Also have you reviewed: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/index.html

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thank you give me some clues. The application speed is fast a lot now after I close the Instant Run and use `RUN` but not `DEBUG`. I feel the mainly reason is `DEBUG`.